# Website working, but not on iphone. XMLHttpRequest() error

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have created this website

http://www.tylertracy.com/testing/Xml/App%20veiwer%205-28.php

It works fine on most browsers and on iPhone simulators, but it doesn't work on a real iPhone. I have narrowed it down to the XMLHttpRequest(). It seems that when I am getting the xml, I can not read the children of [object Element] it returns  undefined. This is very baffling i do not understand.

Here is my code for getting the XML

```
function convertXml (path) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",path,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xml=xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("app");
    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= xml.length-1; i++) {
        foo[i] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j <=xml[i].children.length-1; j++) { // get all children of the app and make it a part in the object
            foo[i][xml[i].children[j].tagName] = xml[i].children[j].innerHTML.trim();//super complicated
        } 
     }
    return foo;
}
```

After much experimenting i have discovered that on iPhone the request returns a [object Document] while the computer returns a [object XMLDocument]. I don't know what this means, but i feel like it is where my problem is coming from. is there a way of maybe converting between these?

I have since then updated the code to jQuery seeing if the issue still persists, which it does.

Here is the new jQuery

```
function getXML (path) {
//gets text version of the xml doc
var response = $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
                    url: "testingXml.xml",   
                    async: false,
                  }).responseText;
//converts text into xmlDoc
parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(response,"text/xml");
return xmlDoc;
}

function xmlToObject (x) {
var xml = x.getElementsByTagName("app"); //get all the xml from the root
var foo = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= xml.length-1; i++) {
    foo[i] = {}; // make the object
    for (var j = 0; j <=xml[i].children.length-1; j++) { //get all of the children of the main tag
        foo[i][xml[i].children[j].tagName] = xml[i].children[j].innerHTML.trim();  //super complicated
    }
}
return foo;
}
```

Then to get the array, you would write this code `xmlToObject(getXML("testingXml.xml"))`

The issue is still happening, on computer it is fine, but on iPhone (Google, Safari, Firefox, Oprah) It seems that the xml just isn't displaying.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

in the Google Chrome console when opening your page. This could be why it won't load on iOS: instead of just logging a warning, Apple decided to ignore such requests on mobile devices to prevent the browser from freezing.

Try with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",path,true);
```

and a `xhr.onload` handler as described in [MDN's "Synchronous and asynchronous requests"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: I have looked on many websites, and places like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp don't use true. They use false and it works on the iPhone. I am also getting a response on the iPhone, i just can't read it the same. I can't look at the children of an element.

Comment: Do you know if it is still an issue? @TylerTracy